# HAML Excluding a row from total cost count if boolean column = true in Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, haml

I'm not too familiar with HAML or how this works. The column "archived" under the table store_products is boolean and I want to exclude the product row from total stock price count and stock total if the row's column is true.

Here is the code that is currently implemented:

```
.widget-body.list
  %ul
    %li
      %span.count
        = current_store.products_stock_value
      = t('products.index.total_stock_value')
    %li
      %span.count
        = current_store.products_count
      = t('products.index.all_products')
```

I have tried the following options with no success:

```
.widget-body.list
  %ul
    %li
      %span.count
        = current_store.products_stock_value(filter: 'archived')
      = t('products.index.total_stock_value')
    %li
      %span.count
        = current_store.products_count(filter: 'archived')
      = t('products.index.all_products')
```

and

```
 - if params[:filter] == 'archived'
  = t('current_store.products_stock_value')
- else
  = t('products.index.total_stock_value')
```

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on how `products_stock_value` and `products_count` work and how you'd tell them to ignore `archived: true` rows?

Comment: I am not able to understand your question and what you want, can you please share some more details.

Comment: Essentially the index page shows the total price of stock and the total quantity of stock, however even though every single product is 'archived' (boolean column marked as true) the total price of stock and quantity of stock doesn't change. I want the total stock and quantity to recognize if a product is archived and not display that products cost/quantity.

Comment: Can you please post your associations?